# Oracle SQL get one of each data

Tags: sql, oracle

If I had a table with a column of `Hello` and I had multiple rows with the data 'World' and multiple with the data `Dave` (There are other columns too) and I wanted to select all the different types of data within the `Hello` column.

So basically I would be looking for a return with two results, one being `World` and the other being `Dave`.

Another option would be to count the how many different data pieces there are in the column(2 in this case) and searching with that as a rownum and sorting the results (Although I'd assume this was a very similar search.)

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you don't want duplicates in the result - add `distinct` :

`select distinct hello from yourTable`

and if you want to count different values :

`select hello, count(*) from yourTable group by hello`